# iOS app publishing my position on a web site

Tags: ios, web, gps

I'm looking for an iOS app to show my position on a map embedded in a website that I own (personal use).

Something like the Apple "Find My Friends" built in app, but with the additional feature of publishing position.

It will be used to track work vehicles so there are no privacy concerns at all.

The app can be free or paid (max 100€ per device, no monthly subscription), license doesn't matter.

Comment: Apple may not like this kind of application (keep active in background, collecting and sending data) because it drains the power. A dedicated GPS tracker, as you mentioned, would be an easier option.

Answer (score 1):

I found many apps and I chose Followmee because it works in the background, even if the app is closed and there is a cheap JSON API access.

Other apps miss this functions.

Also I'm evaluating to buy a dedicated GPS tracker like FindMySpot.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  I know it's been a long time, but can you update it to include links?